# Adding pop out menu to iPhone app

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to create a pop put page sort of like a modal view that doesn't cover the entire page? But instead this view should be able to have buttons and slide in and out based on a user touch up inside? Does anyone know how this can be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

UIAlertView can be used for this, as can UIActionSheet. I think that you can find example code for both with relative ease. If not, I can post something.

Comment: yea i know those two can work for making a pop out menu, im looking for a sliding menu, that comes from the left lets say of the page and dissapears back.